# ConcurrentBag is not accassible from another Thread? [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am looking for a solution, where I can store my custom Class objects, and be able to read it from multiply threads. (Other actions, like add, remove can be done from GUI, I only need to find an object from the list, and call a procedure on them).

I have tried several things, but I always somehow end up with a `NullReferenceException`.

My Code on Form1:

```
 Friend conc As New Concurrent.ConcurrentBag(Of Item)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim thr As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Feltolt)
    thr.Start()
End Sub
Public Sub Feltolt()
    For x As Integer = 0 To 100
        conc.Add(New Item() With {.Value = x})
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim thr As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Leker)
    thr.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Leker()
    Dim d As New SeekerMeeker
    MsgBox(d.GetValue(1))
End Sub
```

Code of SeekerMeeker class:

```
Public Function GetValue(val As Integer) As Integer
    Return Form1.conc.SingleOrDefault(Function(t) t.Value = val).Value
End Function
```

However it seems to "not see" the Form1 because it is accessed from a thread. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that your collection is not accessible. The problem is that you're trying to get an item from a different collection than you add the item to in the first place. That second code snippet is run on a secondary thread and it uses the default instance of `Form1`. Default instances are thread-specific, so you're using a different `Form1` object than you're looking at on screen and, therefore, a different `Form1` object than the one containing the collection you added the item to.

You really shouldn't be accessing the form directly from that `SeekerMeeker` object in the first place. That's bad design. If you are going to do it that way though, you need to actually pass the existing `Form1` instance into that object from the outside and use that, rather than trying to get the instance on the inside on a different thread.

To learn more about default instances and passing data among forms, I suggest that you read my blog posts [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html) and [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html). The second one has three parts and you should read all three. The last one is the proper way to do things.

EDIT:

The most obvious solution to the problem is to pass the data into the object that needs it when you create it. You could implement your `SeekerMeeker` class like this:

```vb
Public Class SeekerMeeker

    Private items As ConcurrentBag(Of Item)

    Public Sub New(items As ConcurrentBag(Of Item))
        Me.items = items
    End Sub

    '...

End Class
```

and then create an instance in your form like so:

```vb
Dim d As New SeekerMeeker(conc)
```

Now the `SeekerMeeker` object has access to the same `ConcurrentBag` object as the form does, so it will see any changes that the form makes to it. This is what you need to do, i.e. pass around the data you need, rather than expecting to pluck it out of the air via the default instance.

Experienced developers generally don't use default instances at all anyway. They are a nicety for beginners and VB6 developers. They don't exists in C# and no one complains about that because they aren't required. Just follow the principles of OOP and you'll be fine.

Comment: I've read all the blogpost, yet I am not sure how to achive what I really want. I need to have a list (or some container), that is accessible from multiply classes, and be able to read it even in a thread.

Comment: @Mesos, you cannot access a form object via the default instance on a secondary thread. That's the way it is so wishing it was different won't help. Just pass the collection object into the `SeekerMeeker` object when you create it and then it has access to it on any thread. I'll provide a code example in the answer.